# Pre Installing Java Components for a web app

Tags: java, oracle, jogl

I am a network admin and am having an issue with Java.
For give my naivety. I have a web based oracle application that my clients run.
The latest release of Java has caused it to stop working in IE.
The application uses the jogl library to render various files.
The issue is, when IE spawns the window it should give a security warning the first time it is run but since the last java update, the window never comes to the forefront.
If firefox is installed on the machine, I can accept the security exception and then it works fine in IE.
Is there a way that I can use a machine as a template and then build a deployment package to push to all of my machines via vbs or batch files.
Is there a way to copy exceptions from one machine to another?

The name of the component is autovue from oracle.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: COrrect me if I am wrong but I think you are trying to run a Java applet in IE which gives you a security exception. What exactly is that exception? Maybe this'll help. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175622

Comment: ava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.agile.ui.fileupload.upload.client.DownloadApplet.class

Comment: We have the certificates correct.